# Second bootstrap navbar overlapping a dropdown-menu from the first navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two fixed-top navbars, the dropdown-menu from the first one gets overlapped by the second navbar. Tried messing around with z-index, positioning and overflow.. Also found a couple somewhat related questions but nothing seems to be helping. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Link to
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanlal/dpv7e1zy/37/)

Image below showing the nature of the problem (2nd navbar overlapping dropdown-menu):

[image]

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta>
<title>Navbar overlapping dropdown-menu</title>

<!-- Bootstrap 4 cdn's & jquery dependency -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- first navbar with dropdown-menu -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-sm">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 1 </a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 2 </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 3 </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 4 </a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- second navbar with top offset -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-primary fixed-top navbar-expand-sm" style="top:56px!important;">
    <p>hello world</p>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, this is a z-index issue. Try adding some styles to get the second `navbar` lower on the z-index. When messing with z-index remember to adjust the siblings that are causing the issue. Adjusting the `.dropdown-menu` wouldn't do anything because the issue was with parent elements.

You could do this:

```css
.navbar {
  z-index: 90;
}

.navbar+.navbar {
  z-index: 80;
  top:56px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta>
  <title>Navbar overlapping dropdown-menu</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 cdn's & jquery dependency -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- first navbar with dropdown-menu -->
  <nav class="navbar bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-sm">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 1 </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 2 </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 3 </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 4 </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- second navbar with top offset -->
  <nav class="navbar bg-primary fixed-top navbar-expand-sm">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ah i was being silly then. Was targeting `dropdown-menu` instead of the parent... thanks for the solution. `top:` field isn't necessary btw

Comment: I am running into this exact issue, and I wonder... will this issue affect all two-navbar designs? Is this problem best described a Bootstrap bug, or the web developer's failure (to RTFM?), or something else? Clearly a CSS expert can understand the problem. As an expert, can you characterize this issue a bit please?

Answer (score 1):

Added two class `.front` and `.back` and updated the z-index value.

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpv7e1zy/41/)

**CSS:**

```
.front{
 z-index: 2000 !important;
}
.back{
 z-index: -1 !important; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- first navbar with dropdown-menu -->
<nav class="navbar bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-sm front">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 1 </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 2 </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 3 </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 4 </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<!-- second navbar with top offset -->
<nav class="navbar bg-primary fixed-top navbar-expand-sm back" style="top:56px!important;">
<p>hello world</p>
</nav>
```

Reference for `z-index` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index